# Does $(this) affect performance like $([selector])?

Tags: jquery, performance, this

When using jQuery, I know that you should store an object rather than repeatedly transversing the DOM:

```
// This is good
var something = $(".some-class")
```

My question is does the jQuery `$(this)` have a similar performance issue? Should I be doing this:

```
// should I do this?
var current_object = $(this)
```

with `$(this)`?

(This is my obligatory `this` is confusing joke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` isn't free. It instantiates a new jQuery object.  But compared to traversing the DOM, it's very nearly free.

This level of optimization is usually unnecessary.  Write code that's readable, and optimize this sort of thing only when you experience performance bottlenecks.

My rule, for something like `var foo = $(this)` is:  Use whatever's easier to read in the situation.

`$(this)` has a pretty clear meaning, so use it when it makes sense.  But if you're doing something where it makes sense to call `$(this)` by another name, do that.

Optimize for you and your fellow coder's time. It's the most valuable resource in the equation.

Comment: If `$(this)` initiates a new jQuery object, then wouldn't `var foo = $(this)` just make a copy of it? That sounds like it would actually *hurt* performance rather than help because now you have two identical objects

Comment: If you only use it once, it would hurt performance. It would help performance if you use it more than once. The same is true for your `$("selector")` example--the variable only helps if you use it more than once.

Comment: Even in the case of using it multiple times though, how would it help? Unlike `$([selector])`, I'd assume that `$(this)` doesn't have to transverse the DOM. Wouldn't `foo` and `$(this)` be basically identically at a low level? Maybe I'm not understanding the nature of jQuery objects. (I'm know we're talking minuscule performance differences here; I'm just curious)

Comment: The difference is that `$(this)` N times creates a jQuery object N times, whereas `var foo = $(this)`, then referencing `foo` three times only creates the jQuery object once.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now (I often forget that $(...) are actually function calls, not some special object syntax)